# Excel VBA: unable to disable DisplayAlert during drag+drop?

Tags: vba, excel, action, messagebox

I'm trying to capture a specific drag and drop event in VBA, and would like to disable the popup "There's already data here. Do you want to replace it?" during this event.

I have the basic event of a drag+drop from cell [D1] to cell [E1] captured, but for some reason I'm unable to disable the popup. Does anyone know why?

Thanks so much.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target(1, 1), [D1]) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "selected " & Target.Address & " - " & Target(1, 1).Value
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target(1, 1), [E1]) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "changed " & Target.Address & " - " & Target(1, 1).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - it works on my 2013 Excel:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target(1, 1), [E1]) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "changed " & Target.Address & " - " & Target(1, 1).Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target(1, 1), [D1]) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "selected " & Target.Address & " - " & Target(1, 1).Value
        Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
    Else
        Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This uses the `SelectionChange` event to catch the user selecting D1 and disables the alert using `Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting`. Any other selection ensures it's enabled. Dragging the value causes another `SelectionChange` which now re-enables the alert for any other overwriting.

Also, you ought to use events to trap user clicking in D1 and then changing to another sheet or closing this one as the alerts could remain disabled.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly, thank you! Agreed, I plan to restore the popup if the user clicks (anywhere else).

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

after the drag and drop code? Move it before it.

Comment: I think Mark is trying to disable the pop up if the event catches the user selecting cell D1 - prior to then dragging it into E1

Comment: CLR, you are correct. I only want to disable popups if D1 is selected, prior to dragging into E1.

Fajka, I attempted your suggestion just for kicks and it had no effect.